# Customizing matplotlib's color scheme

Tags: python, matplotlib, customization, color-scheme

I'm following [Sane color scheme for Matplotlib](http://www.huyng.com/posts/sane-color-scheme-for-matplotlib/), but found that my coloring is [still the same](https://gist.github.com/suntong/6363b1de80e2648641bc) as [the default color scheme](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/stackplot_demo.html). What could be wrong?

I was following [Customizing plots with style sheets](http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html), and use these at the top of my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

Is that the reason? Or something else?

Disclose,

- I've done my own modification to huyng's gist, which was created on Feb 8, 2011. The result is [here](https://gist.github.com/suntong/722cb51ee95f3f19eb71).
- The reason for my own modification is listed [there](https://gist.github.com/suntong/722cb51ee95f3f19eb71) as well.
- Where I put the file is explained [there](https://gist.github.com/suntong/722cb51ee95f3f19eb71) as well, and I did restart iphthon notebook after that.
- The reason for me doing the color scheme customization at all is, quoting from [How to make beautiful data visualizations in Python with matplotlib, Color matters](http://www.randalolson.com/2014/06/28/how-to-make-beautiful-data-visualizations-in-python-with-matplotlib/)

> The default color scheme in matplotlib is pretty ugly. Die-hard matlab/matplotlib fans may stand by their color scheme to the end, but it’s undeniable that Tableau’s default color scheme is orders of magnitude better than matplotlib’s.

**UPDATE:** showing that I am placing a valid `matplotlibrc` file at the correct place (which has explained [here](https://gist.github.com/suntong/722cb51ee95f3f19eb71)):

```
D:\>python
Python 3.5.0 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  1 2015, 11:46:22) [MSC v.1
900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
'D:\\Programs\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\mpl-data\\matplotlibrc
'
D:\>dir D:\Programs\Anaconda3\libs\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\matplotlibrc
 Volume in drive D is New Volume

 Directory of D:\Programs\Anaconda3\libs\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data

12/18/2015  05:34 PM            25,738 matplotlibrc
               1 File(s)         25,738 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

From matplotlib 1.5 you can choose between a set of predefined styles (ggplot included).

If you want to create [your own stylesheet](http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html#defining-your-own-style) you just have to place a valid *[matplotlibrc](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html)* file somewhere and use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.set("/path/to/your/file.mplstyle")
```

And then you could use your own style.

Comment: However, I *am* placing a *valid* `matplotlibrc` file at the *correct* place, which should be picked up by default, without specifying `plt.style.set`, right? Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Yes, it should. Could you post where is the *correct* place to check if it is the correct place? :-)

Comment: The "correct" place may depend on your OS / installation. To see where matplotlib is looking for the default matplotlibrc file, use `print(matplotlib.get_configdir())`